# How to style a button like the image?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a button like this image with PURE CSS. Please could you help me with the CSS ?
[This Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rggof.png)

I am trying using below but not giving exact same result  -

```
.styled {
  border: 0 !important;
  line-height: 2.5;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center !important;
  color: rgba(11,44,20,255) !important;
  border-radius: 8px !important;
  padding: 5px 16px 5px 16px;
  transition: 0.2s all;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top left,
                                  rgba(0, 0, 0, .2),
                                  rgba(0, 0, 0, .2) 100%,
                                  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) !important;
  box-shadow: inset 7px 7px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, .6),
            inset -7px -7px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7) !important;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is closest as I can get without the button background. You can try experimenting with CSS gradients until you hit the actual angle.

```css
#button{
  width: 69px;
  height: 34px;
  position: relative;
  
 background: #3F4E4C;
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(bottom right, #3F4E4C, #7CD9BA);
background: -moz-radial-gradient(bottom right, #3F4E4C, #7CD9BA);
background: radial-gradient(to top left, #3F4E4C, #7CD9BA);
  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
}


#external{
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
  left: 6px;
  background: #3ade66;
  width: calc(100% - 12px);
  height: calc(100% - 12px);
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align:center;
  color: black;
  line-height: 2.2;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">
  <div id="external">Start</div>
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I want achieve the same using pure CSS, not using a background image. Please could you help ?

Comment: I've updated the code snippet, check it. @AtanuRoy

Comment: Thats not exactly giving the 3D kind of view of the button. It more like a old keyboard key.

Comment: Ok then, you can design the button background in photoshop and add it to background css property.

Comment: I am trying to do with pure CSS, any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

Add an onclick event to the image.

```js
function myFunction() {
  alert("Button clicked");
};
```

```css
img {
  /*Disables dragging of the image*/
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  -khtml-user-drag: none;
  -moz-user-drag: none;
  -o-user-drag: none;
  user-drag: none;
  /*Sets the mouse to pointer when hovered*/
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rggof.png" onclick="myFunction();">
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I want achieve the same using pure CSS, not using a background image. Please could you help ?

Comment: The only 2 ways to do a button like an image is to add an onclick event to an image or add a background image to a button

Answer (score 0):

Got the similar view using -

```
.styled {
  border: 0 !important;
  line-height: 2.5;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center !important;
  color: rgba(11,44,20,255) !important;
  border-radius: 10px !important;
  transition: 0.2s all;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top left,
                                  rgba(0, 0, 0, .2),
                                  rgba(0, 0, 0, .2) 100%,
                                  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) !important;
  box-shadow: inset 6px 6px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .3),
            inset -6px -6px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3) !important;
```

}